# Improving the performance of gradient boosting classifier

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, feature-engineering, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I am training a gradient boosting classifier on an imbalanced data but the model is not performing very well. These are the things I have done to improve the model's performance.

1. Balanced the data with SMOTE
2. Added more variables
3. combined features
4. polynomial feature transformation (this did not improve the model's performance)
5. cleaned the data
6. Scaled the data

Except number 4, the other efforts have improved the recall and precision of the model from 34% and 60% respectively to 58% and 51% respectively. Which is good but my aim is to improve the recall and precision to over 70%, is there any other method or technique I can try to get a recall and precision of of over 70?

Comment: Have you checked out the precision-recall curves for your models?

Comment: No, I haven't. I did not check it because I am using only 1 model which is gradient boosting. I read that you can check the precision-recall curve when you are testing more than 1 model. I stand corrected though, the information I read might be wrong.

Comment: I don't follow the logic of needing multiple models for a PR curve. The typical way to draw a PR curve is described [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/91559/43938) after you call a method like `predict_proba` on your model instead of just `predict` (to use `sklearn` terminology). While I would advocate for considering the raw probability predictions given by `predict_proba`, if you must do classification, you're certainly allowed to adjust the threshold.

Comment: Ohh, I see, really helpful  thank you. I will definitely check the PR curve.